# How do I avoid repainting the dom whilst adjusting width?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, dom, repaint

So I'm trying to have these two divs push each-other, but FPS is taking a huge hit, and I know it's due to dom repainting... But can I avoid it?

http://codepen.io/Strongarm/pen/obXmmg

```
document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function(){
   TweenMax.to(".left", 0.5, {width:"100%"});
   TweenMax.to(".right", 0.5, {width:"0%", opacity: 0});
   fullScreen = true;
});

document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function(){
    TweenMax.to(".left", 0.5, {width:"0%", opacity: 0});
    TweenMax.to(".right", 0.5, {width:"100%"});
    fullScreen = true;
});
```

Comment: My guess the problem is with your TweenMax plugin itself. If I'm guessing right, your animations are quite simple, and when implemented using css animation or even jQuery's animate() would be smoother than a river.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you may be able to animate the "transform" attribute instead.  [This link](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) describes why transform is better when it comes to moving elements around - it's possible that it will help with resizing too.

For obvious reasons this won't work in all cases, but you could try:

```
TweenMax.to(".left", 1, {transform: scaleX(100%)});
TweenMax.to(".right", 1, {transform: scaleX(0%)});
```

Comment: I did try that, however as the divs will have images, they stretch.